# Getting a font's styles

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I've noticed in Notepad how some fonts have extended styles. Some have less or more than 4. How do I get those when selecting a font?[image]

Update: I noticed `Font.Styles` skipped some numbers, looking at the ones listed. I decided to try out all of them. After 15, there was nothing.

[image]

Comment: No numbers are skipped.  `FontStyle` is an enum marked with the `FlagsAttribute`.  This means that you can bitwise AND or bitwise OR two of the enum values together to create a new style, without having to define ALL the permutations.  Thus you can do like so:  `Dim style As FontStyle = FontStyle.Bold OR FontStyle.Italic`.  See how you can mix them together.  If you want more information on how this works, look up bit masks on your favorite search engine.

Comment: Also, I'm not certain, but the Font Style box on the FontDialog appears to be all the permutations of FontStyles, FontWeights, and FontStretches available for a given font.

Comment: What do you mean with "How do I get those when selecting a font"? Where's the code you're asking that question for? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did quickly realize I could combine multiple ones. What I mean is that I see different style names, like shown in the first photo. How do I choose those styles? Or if they only apply to certain font types, how do I select them when that particular font is chosen? Say I chose Segoe UI programmatically. How do I choose the font styles shown in the first photo?